# Настроить время сервера

Tags: настройка, php, сервер, vps, mysql

Снимаю `VPS`. В `ispmanager` изменил часовой пояс на `Europe/Kiev (+3)`, а дата и в `php` и в `mysql` не та. Должно быть: `Tue, 27 May 2014 19:35:09 +0300А` выводит: `Tue, 27 May 2014 15:20:09 +0300`. Помогите настроить сервер, я в этом чайник! Очень нужно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задай вручную дату.

> Установка времени из командной строки:
>
> date +%T -s "11:14:00"

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помог!!!! Сам не смог нарыть инфу!Не подскажешь как обновить автоматом? (Я же врядли точное время введу) Например через http://time.in.ua/?

Comment: ntpdate ntp.time.in.ua добавь в /etc/crontab, с пометкой допустим раз  в сутки.Вот как конфигурируется cron - ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

[NTP (англ. Network Time Protocol - протокол сетевого времени) 
 | ru.wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTP)

Comment: почитал, но какой командой обновить из ntp.time.in.ua - не понял...Помоги!

Comment: Если не париться с постоянной и точной синхронизацией то можно один раз запустить `ntpdate ntp.time.in.ua` или периодически, по cron (раз в сутки, раз в час)

Comment: При установке ntp должен появиться демон, который с дефолтными настройками всё синхронизирует без крона.Что за ОС стоит?

Comment: Сейчас вроде набирают оборот атаки NTP amplification, и я не уверен в адекватности изкоробочных настроек ntpd в какой-то там ОС (пока-что о ней ничего не известно). Так-что я-бы тут предпочёл обойтись ntpdate

Comment: ntpdate pool.ntp.org